# In HTML, how do you get a textbox to be next to and on the same horizontal alignment as an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something like those thin strips with a search bar at the top of a website. A great example thereof would be the top section of Stack Overflow's website. Notice the logo, the search bar, and the various buttons. This is pretty much exactly what I'm trying to make, albeit with the logo in the center. When I put the two elements one after the other, they are not on the same elevation. The text box is always above or below the logo image. I've tried putting this in a div, which allowed me to set it to the color I wanted for the background, but it still didn't align properly. I also tried putting the 2 elements in a table, and wrapping each of them in a `<tr>`. This did nothing. Here is the code I have:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" , type="text/css" , href="Zaxent Stylesheet.css">
  <style>
    #top {
      background-color: rgb(181, 230, 29);
      text-align: left;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id=top>
    <table>
      <tr><img src="Zaxent logo 2.png"></tr>
      <tr><input name="search bar search page"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

And if it's relevant, here is my CSS code:

```
h1,
p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'High Tower Text', 'Times New Roman', 'Arial';
  font-size: 40px;
  color: rgb(0, 100, 0);
}

body {
  font-family: 'High Tower Text';
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 46px auto;
}

textarea {
  color: rgb(0, 100, 0);
}

textarea {
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  border-color: rgb(34, 177, 76);
  border-width: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

p.x {
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p.u_can_help_ppl {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `table` element for layout. It is also not a good practice to have spaces in your file resources like images and stylesheet file names.

Comment: There is an element called [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header).

Comment: Also, I would recommend running your code through an HTML validator or using some sort of linter-- there is at least one error (missing quotes around id).

Answer (score 1):

You should use flexbox instead of tables. Sorry if you need it with tables, but the flexbox approach would be:

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<header class="top">
    <div class="logo">
        <img style="display:block;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x30/000000/FFFFFF?text=logo" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="search-bar">
        <input style="padding:5px; width:40vw;" type="text" name="search-bar-field" id="search-bar-field">
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I put one element on top of the other in a table?